In *Breaking Bad*, would the 4th Amendment apply?
In the show Breaking Bad, Hank (a DEA Agent) attempts to arrest Jessie Pinkman and determine if there was a meth lab in Jessie's RV as demonstrated in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HGqPDgAwJI
Hank and the lot owner get into a debate about the 4th amendment and probable cause.
Realistically in the United States and in New Mexico if a meth lab was to be discovered by Hank in the RV after Hank broke into and entered it would the evidence be thrown out due to potentially violation of Jessie's 4th amendment rights?

Whether Hank violated the fourth amendment (yes, because there was no probable cause) is a different question from whether the evidence would be thrown out (not if the court found probable cause). Since you ask what would realistically happen: Hank would pretend to have detected the odour of marijuana, and the court would probably accept Hank's testimony regardless of whether any marijuana was found during the search. You might hope DEA agents wouldn't lie in court, but if they're willing to violate the fourth amendment then they're generally also willing to lie about it to protect themselves.

Of course the 4th amendment applies
Not much point in having it if it didn't.
The protection of the 4th amendment from "unreasonable searches and seizures" means that Frank needs a search warrant which he clearly does not have. To get a search warrant, he must show the court that he has probable cause to believe the search will reveal evidence of illegality.
Based solely on the information in the clip, Hank would struggle to show that he had probable cause to search the RV, that is, “a reasonable amount of suspicion, supported by circumstances sufficiently strong to justify a prudent and cautious person’s belief that certain facts are probably true.” However, there was obviously stuff that went on beforehand that led him to the RV, which may amount to probable cause.
To conduct a legal warrantless search, Frank needs probable cause and a recognised exception to the requirement for a search warrant. As stated above, he doesn't have probable cause so the exceptions are moot but there are a couple that could be argued:

Exigent circumstances "that would cause a reasonable person to believe that entry (or other relevant prompt action) was necessary to prevent ..., the destruction of relevant evidence, ... improperly frustrating legitimate law enforcement efforts United States v. McConney, 728 F.2d 1195 (9th Cir. 1984). However, based on the clip, there's no reason to believe there's any contraband inside the RV.
The motor vehicle exemption which is actively discussed in the scene and comes from Carroll v. United States, 267 U.S. 132 (1925) which is a specific case of exigent circumstances in that a motor vehicle is inherently capable of being moved to avoid a search warrant being executed. By California v. Carney, 471 U.S. 386 (1985), a motor home is subject to the motor vehicle exemption if it is readily mobile - basically, is it primarily configured at the time of the search as a home or a motor vehicle? However, the exemption still needs probable cause.

Ultimately, it's up to the court to decide if any search (which didn't happen) is legal. If it was, what's in the RV is admissible; if it wasn't, it isn't. Based purely on the clip, if Frank had got in, any drug-making equipment inside would not be admissible. A gutsy move by the occupants would have been to let Frank do an illegal search and have all the evidence forever barred from seeing the inside of a courtroom - but they don't know what we know, and for all they knew, Frank might be able to show the search was legal.

"A gutsy move by the occupants would have been to let Frank do an illegal search..." Except as soon as you consent to a search it becomes legal.

The RV is riddled with bullet holes, and this answer is riddled with errors. Hank has probable cause, so he does not need a warrant to search the mobile home.

"A gutsy move by the occupants would have been to let Frank do an illegal search and have all the evidence forever barred from seeing the inside of a courtroom" Considering that Walt was in the RV, that would be a very poor decision.
